# I want to make a button visible when ViewPager get's to page 4, but I get null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

one thing that I found accidentally is that when I put the code in a postDelayed handler it works fine. how can I make it work without postDelayed handler?

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        final SlideFragment fragment = new SlideFragment();
        if (position == 3){

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fragment.btnStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            },0);
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

}
```

Comment: i'm not seeing enough code but i think that without postDelayed your are accessing .bntStart before the view is actually created. you should check if, that method, is called before or after onViewCreated of Fragment class

Comment: Where do you get the null pointer exception?

Comment: Did you hide `bntStart` in default mode ?

Comment: Post your error log here.

Comment: when I remove the postdelay and i get to page 4 get the error.

I made my btn invisible in xml.

ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.hadibastanfar.IntroActivity$ScreenSlidePagerAdapter.getItem(IntroActivity.java:80)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your views might not be getting creating on time for you to call the setVisibility on them. Ideally you'd pass an argument when you create the fragment and from them act on the fragment.

```
if (position == 3){
    final SlideFragment fragment = new SlideFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean("BUTTON_VISIBILITY", true);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

Then in your fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
         ViewGroup containerObject,
         Bundle savedInstanceState){
         //here is your arguments
         Bundle bundle= getArguments(); 

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
        btnStart = view.findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_button);
        if(bundle!=null){
           if(bundle.getBoolean("BUTTON_VISIBILITY", false)){
              btnStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           } 
        }
     return view;
     }
```

**EDIT**

You can use onViewCreated to make sure everythin has been created:

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup containerObject, Bundle savedInstanceState){
                return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false); 
             }

   public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle= getArguments(); 
        btnStart = view.findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_button);
            if(bundle!=null){
               if(bundle.getBoolean("BUTTON_VISIBILITY", false)){
                  btnStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               } 
            }
    }
```

Comment: actually you should wait for onViewCreated method to be called to be sure that the view is created

Comment: the op can catch the button right after it has been created/inflated

Comment: i don't think so. he is saying that he has a null pointer exception; the delay is enough for the view to be loaded/inflated.

Comment: Own, I meant he can catch the button in the fragment itself (like in my solution above). If they're trying to access from outside the fragment (like they're doing above) I completely agree with you that the op needs to wait for onViewCreated.

Comment: the solution above didn't work I still get the same error :(

Comment: so what what I get, is that I'm calling the view before its created, is it possible to make it get created when activity is started?

Comment: did you completly remove the handler? did you replace id_of_your_button with the id of your button?

Comment: did you replace id_of_your_button with the id of your button?

Comment: yes i did replace id_of_your_button with the actual ID of my button.

Comment: strange, okay try with onViewCreated then, I've edited the answer